# Netbeans anagram problem

Tags: netbeans, anagram

Every time I am trying to run a program,an "Anagram" pops up and I cannot run my program.
How to make it disappear?
Thanks

Comment: Which program? This question is un-answerable in its current format.

Comment: Hmm, try to solve the anagram, and then maybe your computer will let you proceed. Kind of like the Sphinx.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess, based on the limited amount of info you have given in this question, is that you have opened the Anagram project as you started to learn Java and NetBeans.

This Anagram project is your 'main project' from the IDE's perspective, so when you use F6, it is running the 'main project'.

To change the main project (and change the target for things like the F6 key), right click on the project that you want to run now and select the 'Set as Main Project' item from the menu that appears.

If you add more info about your situation folks may be able to provide a better answer.